# Catch error in Component from async Vuex Action

Tags: vue.js, async-await, try-catch, vuex

I have an async action, like so:

```
export const fetchTweets = async ({ commit, state }) => {
  const tweetFetchError = error => {
    // throw here?
  }
  try {

    const { oAuthAccessToken, oAuthAccessTokenSecret, user: { id } } = state

    const { data, errors } = await api.fetchTweets(oAuthAccessToken, oAuthAccessTokenSecret, id)

    if (errors && Object.keys(errors).length) return tweetFetchError(errors)

    commit(types.SET_TWEETS, {
      tweets: data
    })
  } catch (error) {
    tweetFetchError(error)
  }
}
```

Which I invoke from my Component, like so:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions(['fetchTweets']),
    async handleFetchTweets () {
      try {
        await this.fetchTweets()
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('errored')
        this.$message.error('Error fetching tweets')
      }
    }
},
```

I call `handleFetchTweets` in mounted.

My question is, how can I catch the error back in the Component? In the Action, this method `tweetFetchError` gets correctly invoked when there's an error, but I'm unsure how to trigger the `catch` in the try/catch back in the Component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to throw the error after you've caught it in the `fetchTweets` method:

```
  ...
  } catch(error) {
    tweetFetchError(error)
    throw error;
  }
}
```

And catch the error using the returned Promise's `.catch` handler:

```
async handleFetchTweets () {
  await this.fetchTweets().catch((error) => {
    console.log('errored')
    this.$message.error('Error fetching tweets')
  });
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I don't get 'errored' in the console (which would suggest my `catch` worked in the Component, but I simply see `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?f777:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?14ed:87)`

Comment: Oh yeah, since it's an async method it's returning a Promise, so you need to use the Promise's `catch` method instead of a try/catch. See my edit